# How can I make the circle object in canvas to movable

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to the circle object movable like move when the mouse clicks and it stops when the mouse is out. The circle is moving when it is clicked, but the problem is creating a lot of circles. I just wanted to have one circle in the canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  this.down = true;
  this.X = e.pageX;
  this.Y = e.pageY;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  this.down = false;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (this.down) {
    with(ctx) {

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    this.X = e.pageX;
    this.Y = e.pageY;
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" style='background-color:#EEE;' width='500px' height='200px'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas every time you draw in your `mousemove` event using `ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height)`, and then redraw your circle like so:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  this.down = true;
  this.X = e.pageX;
  this.Y = e.pageY;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  this.down = false;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (this.down) {
    // clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    this.X = e.pageX;
    this.Y = e.pageY;
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" style='background-color:#EEE;' width='500px' height='200px'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful :) For this code,  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 0, 0 mean start with any place on canvas?

Comment: Also, I have another question, if I want to create two circles, which is pink and yellow color circles; can I store in variables then mentioned in the if condition that have circles act same functions as on this example?

Comment: @Kijimu7 Hi, sorry for the late reply. The `clearRect()` method essentially removes all drawings, and within the dimensions of the rectangle specified. The `0, 0` means to position this rectangle in the top left, and `canvas.width, canvas.height` means make the width and height of the rectangle the width and height of the canvas it the height of the

Comment: @Kijimu7 for multiple circles you would need to look at creating two objects (either using classes or `{}` syntax).